# android draw panel set draw text

Tags: android, panel, draw, paint

I have made a draw panel. I want to add text to my panel background, but I've failed. I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
 public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);
    mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] {1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
    mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(5, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
}

 public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setTextSize(50);
    p.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mCanvas.drawText("HI", getLeft()+10, getTop()+30, p);
}
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

    for (FingerPath fp : paths) {
        mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

        if (fp.emboss)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
        else if (fp.blur)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);

        mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);


    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

I set "HI" `drawText`, but it does not show.

Thanks in advance.

this is my code
https://github.com/cool3690/bsic
and I hope I can do like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEqFu.png)

Comment: You've created your own `Bitmap` there. Unless you then somehow draw that `Bitmap` to an on-screen `View`, you aren't going to see it.

Comment: Mike M how to do it? I set a picture on panel background,but not show

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Mike M I have update my question

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're calling `init()`, but the `mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)` call in `onDraw()` is drawing that color over the text you draw in `init()`, covering it.

Comment: Mike M, After several try I solve the problem, thank,can you move your comment to answer,I will select it